# JMeter: connection to multi instance mq

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq

Project is needed in making fail-over tests. We use JMeter for sending messages to IBM MQ queue. Queue manager is in Multi-Instance configuration.

Our test has next steps:

1. Sending messages to active instance MQ
2. In some moment we kill MQ process and continue messaging

What about JMeter, we use next scenario:

1. Request: Connection with sending messages to the first instance of MQ
2. If Controller: ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}==false

   1. Request: Connection with sending messages to the second instance of MQ

When we start test, we get next states:

1. Sending message to the first instance is OK
2. Kill the first instance. In that case we must to connect to the second instance through IF Controller. But we get error RC2538

If we start test with killed the first instance, connection to the second instance is OK and JMeter sends messages.

Help anyone, please!!!

Comment: In your JMeter (Groovy) code, you need to add reconnection logic.  There is no magic code in MQ.

Comment: Please add the configuration of the two different connections (first and second instance) to your question. MQRC 2538 means MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE which suggests you perhaps have a typo in your configuration somewhere.

Comment: How do you kill the first instance?  Do you use endmqm?  If you have specified that you want to use mq automatic reconnect then you must add -r or -s depending on what hit are doing for the client to reconnect.

Comment: @JoshMc we use kill -9